# XMLHttpRequest OnReadyStateChange not returning correct status on IE11

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

I have this form to fill in email address and submit button, if server handle email address successfully, the success component should show up, if not, the error component should show, right now when submitted, both chrome and IE11 will send email from server to email address successfully, but only chrome shows success message while IE11 showing error message first and then the success message show up. I am wondering what's the problem? thx

```
Form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
handleSubmit();
});


function handleSubmit() {
var url = 'https://serveURLXXXXX';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onerror = function () {
  console.log('** An error occurred while sending email address.');
};
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    emailSuccess.style.display = 'block'; //(here an component will show: 
you email has been sent, successfully)
  } else {
    emailError.style.display = 'block';  //(there is someting wrong with 
the email sending).
  }
};
xhr.send(
  JSON.stringify({email: emailAddressInput.value})
);
}
```

Comment: You could try to set the debugger to debug your code (inside the onreadystatechange and onerror function), then, try to check the transfer data and the error message.

Comment: `onreadystatechange` fires four times with the different `readyState` and `status` values, should be the same in Chrome too. Maybe you should listen to `xhr.onload` instead?

Comment: thank you guys very much, I will try.